# C99: segmentation fault when assigning values in rectangular 2D arrays (But the same algroithm works fine in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, c99

Basically I'm trying to solve the LCS (Longest Common Subsequence) problem. I need to construct a table, which can be represented by a 2D array. Here is part of the code in C:

```c
void get_lcs(int arraySize, char seqA[arraySize], char seqB[arraySize]) {
    int x = strlen(seqA), y = strlen(seqB);
    //seqA and seqB are both arrays. They have a fixed length of 1000. Not all of it is filled, obviously.
    //Hence why I used the strlen() function

    int table[x+1][y+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= x; j++) {
            table[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //Generate a table that looks like this:
    /*
        0   1   2   3   4   5... (seqA, x)
       ----------------------
    0  |0   0   0   0   0   0
    1  |0   /   /   /   /   /       (/) are place holders. They are empty values (0), for now.
    2  |0   /   /   /   /   /       When the sequence value matches (e.g. X2 == Y3), the value of
    3  |0   /   /   /   /   /       the corresponding cell (X2Y3) will be it's diagonal cell's value increased by 1.
    4  |0   /   /   /   /   /       If not, it will take the largest value of the top and right cell.
    5  |0   /   /   /   /   /
    ... (seqB, y)

    */
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= x; j++){
            if (i == 0 || j == 0){
                continue;
            }
            if (seqB[i-1] == seqA[j-1]){
                table[i][j] = table[i-1][j-1] + 1;
            } else {
                table[i][j] = max(table[i-1][j], table[i][j-1]);
            }
        }

    printf("\n");
    //print out the table
    //for debug use
    printf("          ");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("%c   ",seqA[i]);
    }
    printf("\n  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < (x+1); i++) {
        printf("----");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("  |");
        }else{
            printf("%c |",seqB[i-1]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= x; j++) {
            printf("%4d",table[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int max(int a, int b) {
    // compare max value between two integers. Return the larger one. If they are equal, return their value.
    int value = 0;
    if (a > b) {
        value = a;
    } else {
        value = b;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The program will ask for input for two integer sequences (The function that ask for input is not here because it is irrelevant). If I input (`23412`) and (`23564`) it will display something like this:

```
Table construction finished
dimension (X,Y) = 5,5

          2   3   4   1   2
  ------------------------
  |   0   0   0   0   0   0
2 |   0   1   1   1   1   1
3 |   0   1   2   2   2   2
5 |   0   1   2   2   2   2
6 |   0   1   2   2   2   2
4 |   0   1   2   3   3   3
```

However, if I input two sequence that has a significant difference in length, for example, (`123324324235`) and (`231`), The program will instead give me a segmentation error (core dumped), and nothing else. Like this:

```
Table construction finished
dimension (X,Y) = 3,11
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have write a similar code in Python to see where the problem is, but that code just worked fine with those numbers. Here is the code in Python 3:

```python
x = len(seqA)
y = len(seqB)
table = [[0 for j in range(x+1)] for i in range(y+1)]

for i in range(y+1):
    for j in range(x+1):
        if i == 0 or j == 0:
            continue
        elif seqB[i-1] == seqA[j-1]:
            table[i][j] = table[i-1][j-1] + 1
        else:
            table[i][j] = maximum(table[i-1][j],table[i][j-1])
    print(table[i])
```

Here is the output:

```
# Two input sequences (length = 12, 3) are:
123324324235
231
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: The debugger is a great tool for diagnosing core dumps.   You'll be able to see exactly which line of code was running when it crashed, then inspect array indices and other variables to figure out why.

Comment: This code could easily cause a crash: `int table[x+1][y+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= x; j++) {
            table[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }` — if the strings are of different lengths, you have your subscripts back to front in the assignment (it should be `table[j][i] = 0;` given the way you have `i` and `j` indexing.  Or you could swap the limits `x` and `y` on the two loops and leave the assignment unchanged — that might be more natural.  I've no idea if that's the only problem.

Comment: The condition in the second pair of nested loops `if (i == 0 || j == 0){
                continue;
            }` is a bit silly — start the loop indexes (`i` and `j`) at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler I have solved this problem. For whatever reason dynamically allocate the array using melloc() seems to do the trick for me. It confuses me at first as I remember Linux call stack have an 8 MB limit and seems like if I used a disproportional array it is hitting that limit. I used int **table = malloc((y + 1) * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        table[i] = malloc((x + 1) * sizeof(int));
    }